# Rails 3.2 + OSX: Cannot install rmagick gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion, rmagick

I am trying to install an RoR app from Github and while running `bundle install`, I get this error:

```
Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:193:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried to run `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'`, but I got the same error.

I am running on Mac OS X Lion. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, what do you mean exactly `Yar`? I am a bit lost now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run:

```
brew link imagemagick
```

Comment: If you get a `is not writable' error, the following answer should help:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/16844923/3507417

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a compiler. XCODE command line tools, or just install gcc.

Comment: If you have homebrew installed run `brew doctor`. It might give you some hints on what's missing in your system to install native libraries.

Comment: I tried to install `imagemagick` and I got this message: `Error: imagemagick-6.7.7-6 already installed, it's just not linked`. How to link it?

Comment: `brew link --overwrite  imagemagick` helped me. Thank you guys.

Comment: hmm.. @AnatoliyKukul. You should write your answer below and the OP should accept it, I didn't help much

Answer (score 1):

I could not install the rmagick gem either...

To get Imagemagick installed correctly I first

```
brew remove libtool
brew install libtool --universal
```

Then I was able to install Imagemagick using this command:

```
brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
```

Then the rmagick gem installed correctly

The error message I was getting when rmagick would not install looked like:

```
linking shared-object RMagick2.bundle
ld: file not found: /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [RMagick2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

This was for Imagemagick 6.8.9-8 and rmagick 2.13.2