# Error when trying to "brew link autoconf"

Tags: rvm, homebrew

When I try to "brew link autoconf" in the terminal I keep getting this error.

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/emacs/site-lisp
/usr/local/share/emacs is not writable. You should change its permissions.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to make sure that all the files and folders in /usr/local are writable by you.  You can do this by typing the following command

```
chown -R yourusername /usr/local
chmod -R u+w /usr/local
```

You may have to use sudo for those commands to work.

After you do this, try linking again.

Comment: I tried this but only got a bunch of "chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/git/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/I18N.pm: Operation not permitted" this type of things

Comment: Have you tried to run the brew command again? You will see an error whenever you try to change permissions on a file you don't own, but it might have sucessfully changed.  You can also try to change ownership of the files with `chown -R yourusername /usr/local`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct but i deleted this /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/emacs/site-lisp. After deleting it, it worked.

Comment: It works because it's not trying to perform that link anymore.  This just fixed the symptom but it might return when homebrew needs to link something in the future.  Take a look at the permissions and ownership of all the files and folders homebrew needs to access, and make it so that you have read/write access on all these.  That will fix the problem.

Answer (score 11):

(sudo) chown -R yourusername /usr/local

Answer (score 2):

I had to run

```
chmod -R u+w /usr/local
brew link --overwrite autoconf
brew install htop
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried under /usr/local/share/emacs/

```
sudo chmod 777 site-lisp
```

and then

```
brew link autoconf
```

and problem solve!

mac@Anna_mac : /usr/local/share/emacs : brew link autoconf
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69... 22 symlinks created

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the following commands

```
chown -R yourusername /usr/local
chmod -R u+w /usr/local
brew link --overwrite autoconf
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change brew owned by root.

then you can use below command.

```
sudo brew link xxxx
```

Quote from github, this is not a bug, it is designed:

> jacknagel commented on 4 Feb 2012
>
> brew install will not work with root privileges unless brew itself is
>   owned by root. @jacknagel Collaborator jacknagel commented on 4 Feb
>   2012
>
> (this is by design.)